# controlling animation differently with each mouse click

Tags: jquery, click, controls, sprite

I want to have a character that, each time you click on that character, it does something completely different than the previous click. I have created about 113 frames so far for the character for now. I may stop there, or I may want to create more frames in the future. The point being, I consider myself a beginner web developer, and I would like to know how to give my character a good degree of control depending on when you have clicked on it. For instance, this is the code I have so far...

```
(function() {
var play_on_click = [70, 22, 21];
var play_index = 0;

$('#stacheguy2').click(function() {
    var current_play = play_on_click[play_index];

    play_index++;
    if (play_index > play_on_click.length-1) {
        play_index = 0;
    }

    $(this).sprite(fps: 30, no_of_frames: 113, play_frames: current_play});
});
})();
```

At the moment, this allows me to do the following:

On first mouse click: Play first 70 frames
On second mouse click: Play the next 22 frames
On third mouse click: Play the next 21 frames

However, I'm curious to know if it's possible to, for instance, allow the character to move across the screen to the right on the third mouse click. What if that character also changed it's z-index on the that third click?

Is any of this kind of control possible?

Thank you so much for your time if you are able to offer some advice!

Comment: I'd love to see a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) of this functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add functions in your `play_on_click` array, then check for type of the current index (may be int or function). Javascript is beautiful because it's very easy to do so:

```
(function() {
     var isFunction = function(obj) {
        return typeof(obj) == "function";
      };

     // Changing the array, adding a function at third step instead of int
     var play_on_click = [70, 22, function (){
         // Does any action on the guy, for example your zIndex stuff
         $('#stacheguy2').css('zIndex', 2);
         // return number of frames
         return 21 ;
     }];
     var play_index = 0;

     $('#stacheguy2').click(function() {
         var current_play = play_on_click[play_index];

         play_index++;
         if (play_index > play_on_click.length-1) {
            play_index = 0;
         }

         // If function 
         if ( isFunction ( current_play ) ) {
             // run function and get returned number of frames
             current_play = current_play () ;
         }
         $(this).sprite(fps: 30, no_of_frames: 113, play_frames: current_play});
     });
})();
```